# Server sent events with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I can't seem to find any good example of server sent events.

My goal is to send 2 messages to 2 separate divs but i'm new with javascript so i don't know how to parse these two messages, can anyone point me in right direction?

And if someone can explain me how SSE works, can I run this php script `send.php` to push updates to web page or javascript runs script itself?

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$message = $row['message'];
$user = $row['user'];
echo "{$message}\n\n";
echo "{$user}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

And this is my HTML/Javascript:

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
{
var source=new EventSource("send.php");
source.onmessage=function(event)
{
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
};
}
else
{
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just send the events back to the server as a JSON encoded string and indicate which div should get what message.

```
$arr = array(
    'user' => $row['user'],
    'message' => $row['message']
)
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Then, parse the JSON response from the server and perform logic against it. Let's assume the two divs have an ID of `user` and `message`

```
source.onmessage=function(event){
    var $data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    for(key in obj){
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { //ensure that we're not up in the prototype chain
            document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = $data[key];    
        }
    }
}
```

The relationship here is of course that `key` will be either `user` or `message`. We also expect there to be 2 divs, `id="user"` and `id="message"` that we can modify the innerHTML for. This is not a requirement, but aids in simplifying the process.

Comment: So, this should work without refreshing browser and i could run this from server (administration panel in PHP) to push messages to already opened browsers?

Comment: Whatever data exists in that script will be created dynamically if you build it that way.

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as solution because it seems to have everything I need. But can you please show me on my example how should be done by using $row['message'] and $row['user'] to update <div id="user"></div> and <div id="message"></div> if it's not to much of a problem for you. Please

Comment: What I've shown you above is all you need. remove your `echo` statements, replace it with my `$arr = array(` constructor, and add the `echo json_encode($arr)` and you're done.

Comment: How do I run this javascript function to load php file and show values? In other words, what triggers the event on the server that causes a message to be sent?

Comment: In this case, you need to bind to an event. the `jQuery` library will be extremely handy in simplifying this equation. It's a javascript library built to give you tools to make this all more readable and much syntactically simpler.

Comment: So with jquery i can invoke this function on all open webbrowsers to give them fresh data?

Comment: @user2813059 You need to perform some logic to make the request for that data to be updated. If you are looking to use `server-sent events` to push data to ALL open browsers, then you're going to need to do much more learning here. You need an event to fire of the SSE request, such as a `timeout` function. If you're looking to make a real time "update" in other browsers, there's much more ahead, and it cannot be explained in this answer.

Comment: I'm confused now, how is SSE fired here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp
But nevermind, i'll try something.